# How to customize an open source project

Tags: open-source, osticket

I am currently working on an open source ticketing software named OsTicket. I am using *OsTicket* 1.7.0 and I have customized it a lot and all the customization are in the original source code of Osticket. So, Now I want to upgrade the version but It's little difficult becuase we customized the original source code of older version. So I don't want to make same mistake again. Is there any way I can customize Osticket without affecting the source code which will make it easier to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can use admin panel and maybe find some values in mysql database. But it will cover only some minor changes. If you want to do bigger modifications, you will apply them again after upgrade(because your version is quite old). There is no other way. In OsTicket 2, there will be more space to modify screens and other things in Admin panel.